# How much deterministic is Physics from Unity3d In 2019?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is the 3D Physics of Unity deterministic across different platforms, like Android and IOS?

I saw the 2D physics is not (acros different platforms):
https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015178512-Determinism-with-2D-Physics

> "However, for your application, you might want strict determinism. As
>   such, you would need to know whether Box2D can produce identical
>   results on different binaries and different platforms. Generally,
>   Box2D cannot do this. The reason is that different compilers and
>   different processors implement floating point math differently, which
>   affects the results of the simulation."

But I saw the 3D physics maybe is?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html

> "To achieve deterministic physics results, you should pass a fixed
>   step  value to Physics.Simulate every time you call it. Usually, step
>   should be a  small positive number. Using step values greater than
>   0.03 is likely to produce  inaccurate results."

https://blogs.unity3d.com/pt/2018/11/12/physics-changes-in-unity-2018-3-beta/
In the article above says:

> Enhanced determinism PhysX guarantees the same simulation result when
>   all the inputs are exactly the same."

So in theory it is possible, but in reality (you know dealing with physics across different platforms, like Android, IOS and others) is very complex.
I'd like to know from someone how tried to implement this in 2019, if this is possible nowadays?

So if it is deterministic, what should I put in code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhysX, used in Unity3D is not deterministic. However, there is a new physics package in unity 2018.3, that in theory does what you need

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@0.0/manual/index.html

Comment: Yes, I think the same of you. I posted this on Unity forums (once this stackoverflow not more accepts any discussions, I think this platform will die someday) https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-much-deterministic-is-physics-from-unity3d-in-2019.711311/